# How can I start a 'screen' session as non-root user

Tags: users, gnu-screen, non-root-user

Is there a way I can open a new 'screen' session on my RHEL box as a non-root user? When I try to open a new screen using the 'screen' command as a non-root user, it fails and I get the following message:

```
Cannot open your terminal '/dev/pts/2' - please check.
```

I researched a little bit and found people suggesting to change the permissions on /dev/pts to grant the non-root user (who is trying to open the screen) a read/write access. Though it may work, it does not look like a neat solution. Is there a 'legal' way that allows a non-root user to open a screen session?

Edited : I have this issue on my RHEL 5.5, 6.2 and 6.5 machines. The screen version on all these boxes are 'Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06'.

P.S:- I know that I can open a screen session as root and 'su' to start my command/process, but that is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known problem, if you ssh as root somewhere and then `su` to become a normal user:

```
$ ssh root@server
# su -l anthon
$ screen 
Cannot open your terminal '/dev/pts/3' - please check.
```

It is e.g. described in [these posts from 2005](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/problem-using-screen-cannot-open-your-terminal-%27-dev-pts-0%27-please-check-338313/#post1721823)

The solution is to directly login as the user you want the `screen` session to run as.

Comment: I log in as normal user. Still cannot run `screen`.

Comment: Maybe `screen` is not installed on your system, or some other unknown reason that causes that. Impossible to tell. You should post a new question (with a lot more information), and delete your comment.

Comment: The VPS is managed, and the support says it is not supported on managed systems. Could I use a ready binary of screen or something?

Comment: What part of *you should post a new question* do you not understand? Comments are not for posting questions and answers. Sigh.... `screen` runs as root (using setuid), so if you can arrange that on your managed system, just install the binary from the .deb or .rpm. In your case I would look at using `tmux` instead (which doesn't require running as root.

Comment: Thanks I perfectly understand what you said but I’m pretty sure it will be set as duplicate if I post

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `script /dev/null` before using `screen`.
After leaving `screen` you have to `exit`.

Comment: Or have it all in one command so you don't have to exit the script session: `sudo -su user script -c bash /dev/null`