# Init script for a daemon to run screens on CentOS

Tags: bash, centos, gnu-screen, init-script, init.d

I have a question concerning a init.d script.
Currently I have a init script that launches a custom daemon as follows:

```
sudo -u "$user" $cmd >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$stderr_log" &
echo $! > "$pid_file"
```

Daemon works as long as I run the init script as root.
The daemon needs access to create screens, but because of CentOS 6.7 I need to use a workaround to allow non-root users to run screens by using the command ´script´ ([How can I start a 'screen' session as non-root user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160523/how-can-i-start-a-screen-session-as-non-root-user)) and I end up with the following line that starts the daemon perfectly as a non-root user.

```
sudo -u "$user" bash -c "script -c \"$cmd\"" >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$stderr_log" &
```

Issues begin when I try to echo and pipe the pid of the process to the pid file as it gives the pid of the ´script´ command and not of the daemon itself.

Does anyone have a suggestion or a solution for getting the pid of the daemon?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
sudo -u "$user" bash -c "script -c \"$cmd& echo $! > \"$pid_file\"\"" >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$stderr_log" &
```